# Redis is it possible to update multiple hset keys(not fields) using mset

Tags: redis

Is there a way to use MSET for HSET keys ? I am trying to update multiple HSET keys(not fields) in a single operation to save on network traffic.

Comment: I think the only way to do it atomically will be creating a Lua script

Comment: i am not more concerned about reducing network delay costs than atomicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save on network trips, you'll want to use pipelining. Using Lua is possible, but not as tunable as pipelining where you can find and set the optimum number of commands per execute for your dataset.

And as an added bonus you get experience with a re-usable technique.

Comment: Yes, I needed up using pipelines for now. But Lua scripts are the most efficient when you are not worried about atomicity

Answer (score 3):

No and yes.

No, MSET does not support this behavior, nor does Redis have a command to do that.

Yes, it is possible to update multiple Hash keys with a single command to reduce network traffic - the way to do it is with Lua scripting.