# How to set keyvalue pairs with expiry in StackExchange Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using this function to set multiple key values.

```
bool StringSet(KeyValuePair<RedisKey, RedisValue>[] values, When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Is there any way to include expiry time to these keyvalues?

Comment: Stack exchange redis doesn't expose an interface for that. You  could accomplish it by sending multiple sets as a transaction or just pipelining the sets by using the async set method.

Comment: Actually Redis does not expose an API for that. Check [MSET](https://redis.io/commands/mset) vs [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set)

Comment: @thepirat000 ok, got it.

Comment: @Arik I don't think that will reduce roundtrips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis is it possible to update multiple hset keys(not fields) using mset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217306/redis-is-it-possible-to-update-multiple-hset-keysnot-fields-using-mset)

Comment: You can set the expiry on the whole set / array but not on individual key-value pairs.